# 'head' terminated by signal 13 Unix error

Tags: unix

Trying to list the first lines of all text files in a directory ~/UnixCourse. When I type

Code:

```
find ~/UnixCourse -print -type f -name "*.txt" -exec head -1 {} \;
```

I get this error:

```
find: 'head' terminated by signal 13
```

I feel like I am close to the solution. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Also the answer has to be one-lined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me on both OS X 10.10 and Debian:

```
find ~/UnixCourse -type f -name "*.txt" -print -exec head -1 {} \;
```

Comment: But I need the -print in there to print each directory and then the first line of the text file.
Example:
**/home/yourname/UnixCourse/foo.txt**
When in the course of human development

Comment: Alright, it's what you want now. You need the -print after the file name match, so it only prints the directories with the files you're looking for.

Comment: My apologies, yes you are right! I rechecked what I entered and i skipped putting in -print. Thank you. Interesting how the placement of -print will change everything